# Can't create a Task for a Contact through Bulk API

Tags: contact, tasks, bulk-api, xml

I noticed that I can create a `Task` under a `Contact` manually, through Salesforce UI, but I can't create it through the Bulk API.

Can anyone explain me why and if possible, how to overcome this? I think it's a validation issue, I wonder why it doesn't take place with the normal UI. Here's the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
    <result>
        <errors>
            <fields>WhatId</fields>
            <message>Opportunity/Account ID: id value of incorrect type: 003G000002Blwl2IAB</message>
            <statusCode>FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION</statusCode>
        </errors>
        <success>false</success>
        <created>true</created>
    </result>
    <result>
        <errors>
            <fields>WhatId</fields>
            <message>Opportunity/Account ID: id value of incorrect type: 003G000002Blwl3IAB</message>
            <statusCode>FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION</statusCode>
        </errors>
        <success>false</success>
        <created>true</created>
    </result>
</results>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want associate a Task to a Contact you should use WhoId field, not WhatId

Comment: Oh really, I've lost so much time on this and the answer is that stupid? Screw me and thanks a lot, you have saved me from a nightmare